# How is the Kubernetes job queue sorted?

Tags: kubernetes

When jobs cannot be scheduled due to cluster resource limits, are they scheduled in FIFO order when resources free up?

Or is there any other mechanism? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Jobs are scheduled like any other pod.
- The main difference is that Jobs doesn't have ReplicaSet since ReplicaSet is used for managing replication while job does not require replication, its run and is completed.

So to answer your question it will behave just like any other pod regarding scheduling.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What I actually want to know is how the "Sort" step is done in pod scheduling. Say there are multiple pods that cannot be scheduled at the moment, how does Kubernetes decide which pod to schedule once resources free up? I know you can probably configure this, but I'm curious about the default behavior.

Comment: its a long answer, ill try to find time tommorow to explain it.